# UBUNTU: unable to set JAVA_HOME value

Tags: ubuntu, java-home

In Ubuntu, I installed `Maven` and `JAVA 1.8`, installed it and edited the `/etc/environment` file to set `JAVA_HOME` value. My `/etc/environment` is as follows:

```
M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin/java:$M2_HOME/bin"
```

`which java` gives me `/usr/bin/java`, which is already present in `$PATH`.

`ls -ltR /usr/bin/java` gives `/etc/alternatives/java` and `ls -ltR /etc/alternatives/java` gives `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`.

Snapshot of `mvn -version` is as below:

```
root@microservice-deploy:/etc# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.13.0-1008-gcp", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

which means, `JAVA Home` is pointing to some other location.

Where exactly is the `JAVA Home` variable present? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I guess you are looking at `JAVA_HOME`? Can't you set that in `/etc/environment` too if it's not set to a value you like?

Comment: I think this is a question for the unix stackexchange  . Which has been asked previously--  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Answer (score 0):

1. Find user/lib/jvm/jdk-17 (replace jdk-17 with your install version)
2. sudo vim /etc/profile (one can use nano)
3. add:

   ```
          export JAVA_HOME="path that you found"

          export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. Reboot your system
5. To see java_home `echo $JAVA_HOME` To see it is added to path properly `echo $PATH`

Comment: To find jdk path properly use: `readlink -f  $(which java)`. it will print path as **usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java**. just copy the path and remove **/bin/java** from your given path. and apply above method.